# Focus on elements with circle (Tour Guide)

Tags: android

I want to achieve this on my app:

[image]

*(Yes, I don't know the name of this that's because I named the title like that. But an edit will be appreciated.)*

I want this at the first launch of my app (my app also has a welcome tutorial slidable so after the welcome tutorial these will start showing up.)

What is this called and how can I achieve it on my app?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

this library will help you out.

[Tour Guide](https://github.com/worker8/TourGuide)

Comment: Yes, this one is good. But is there an official lib from Google? Because the example I sent you is more "Material" with animations etc.

Comment: I want the exact design with the example I sent.